# Why do subtitles not work when streaming via AirPlay to Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, airplay, streaming, subtitle

Whenever I use AirPlay to watch **streamed content** (*streaming from the web* (via an app or Safari), that is, not from a downloaded movie) from my iPad to my Apple TV, subtitles are never carried over. Why is this? Is there some obscure setting to enable subtitle support in AirPlay/Apple TV?

Comment: What devices are you streaming from? What format is the video you are playing? What format is the subtitle track?

Comment: I'm streaming from various official TV channel apps as well as movie rental apps (like Netflix, for example). I have no idea what format the video or subtitles use.

Answer (score 2):

try Beamer app, it makes subtitle configuration much easier. I never managed to get subtitles on my iTunes -> TV via airplay. Beamer made it easy. Well worth the $15